# Simplify testing of a null variable in an IF statement

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I have this (which will not compile):

```
var list: MutableList<String>? = null

if (list.isNotEmpty()) {

}
```

This will compile:

```
var list: MutableList<String>? = null

if (list!!.isNotEmpty()) {

}
```

However, if list is null, a runtime exception will occur. I could do this:

```
var list: MutableList<String>? = null

if ((list != null) && list.isNotEmpty()) {

}
```

But this seems to be repetitive everywhere you need to test if something is null. Is there a more eloquent way of doing this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the specific case of checking if the list is not null or empty you can use:

```
if (!list.isNullOrEmpty())
```

Comment: OK, that is correct but I failed to provide a proper code sample. I'll mark your solution as accepted and post a separate question that is similar yet different.

Comment: Here's what I really wanted to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736306/test-object-member-for-null-before-executing-if-block

Answer (score 1):

For a list, it's better to avoid handling null state instead handle only empty and non-empty state. refer http://thefinestartist.com/effective-java/43.

Saying that, we don't need to explicitly check for null check and only empty check alone should do the trick.

```
var list : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
list.add("Test1")
list.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.forEach { println(it) }
```

We can use

> takeIf

to check whether the list is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

The first way add this line

```
list = list?:MutableList<String>()
```

Second way

```
val isEmpty = list.isEmpty()?:false

if(isEmpty){}else{}
```

Third way

```
if (!list.isNullOrEmpty())
```

as @AndroidDev suggested

Why are getting an error? Since `!!` require non-null. if the object is null then it will throw `NPE`

Comment: I want to test if the list is empty using an IF statement and execute the IF block if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think most can be done with the [safe operator `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) itself. So if you just want to iterate over the list (or `reduce`, `map`, or whatever), you can just simply do so directly:

```
val sumExpression = list?.joinToString("+") { it.someValue } ?: throw exception? use default value?
list?.forEach { println("an entry in the list: $it") } // if there are entries, just iterate over them... if not, there is nothing to do
list?.also {
   consume(it) // consume now is only called if the list is not null
}
```

Enhancing it then with a condition is also rather easy with [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) or [`takeUnless`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-unless.html) (depending on what you require):

```
list?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
```

Now you still have a nullable list and can again call any of the desired functions as shown before:

```
list?.takeIf( it.isNotEmpty() }?.also {
  consume(it)
}
```

Also a variant instead of `list.isNullOrEmpty()` (already shown by [gpuntos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736071/6202869)) is to compare the possible null value to the expected outcome, e.g.:

```
if(list?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
  // do something with the non-empty list
}
```

In case it is `null` the condition simplifies to basically `null == true` which is `false`. However I wouldn't overuse that too much as then you don't see the actual nullable types so easily anymore. Such a usage may make sense, if what you are trying to calculate isn't already supported in its own extension function (as is with `isNullOrEmpty()`), e.g. for entering the `if` only if the `count` is 4 it makes sense to use something like: `if (list?.count() == 4)`...