# Test object member for null before executing IF block

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
class Countries {
    var list: MutableList<String>? = null
}

val countries = Countries()

if (countries.list!!.isNotEmpty()) {

}
```

At runtime this will raise an exception because list is null. I can do this instead:

```
if ((countries.list != null) && countries.list!!.isNotEmpty()) {

}
```

If I had a boolean member called areInitialized that was nullable, I could create a infix function like this:

```
infix fun Any?.ifTrue(block: () -> Unit) {
    if ((this != null) && this == true) block()
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
countries.areInitialized ifTrue {

}
```

But I can't seem to create something similar for a mutable list.

But I hate having to repeat this test for null on an member field in other parts of code. Is there a simpler way in Kotlin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to stick to the standard as often as you can. So in your example I wouldn't have introduced that `ifTrue`-function, but rather used [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) or [`takeUnless`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-unless.html) in combination with the [safe operator `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) instead, e.g.:

```
countries?.takeIf { it.areInitialized == true }
         ?.also { 
             /* do something with countries */ 
         }
```

Or if you must return a value, exchange `also` with `let` (or see the other [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#scope-functions)).

The same then also works for the list within `countries`:

```
countries?.takeUnless { it.list.isNullOrEmpty() }
         ?.also { 
             /* do something with countries */ 
             it.list!!.forEach(::println)
         }
```

Comment: The ifTrue is nice for boolean testing as it is very short. Was hoping for something similar for other object types.

Comment: from there on it's easy to add additional extension functions to your need, e.g. `fun Countries?.extractNonEmptyList() = this?.takeUnless { it.list.isNullOrEmpty() }?.list ?: emptyList()` (or throw exception or whatever)

Comment: I don't really see a benefit for your `ifTrue`-function... you could even simplify it to just use `if (this == true) block()` and then I don't see any purpose to add such a function if you can just write `if (countries?.areInitialized == true)` instead...